# Mysql query advice/help needed

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a site where candidates can post their resume and employers can post their jobs.

The employers can post a job with multiple qualifications and I saved it in database like this `PHP,Javascript,ASP`. Now I want admin to be able to select the candidates who are eligible for a post.

I have written the query:

```
$sql = "
        SELECT
            cand_f_name,
            cand_l_name,
            cand_qualification,
            cand_phone,
            cand_email,
            cand_experience_yr,
            cand_experience_mn,
            cand_message,
            cand_id
        FROM
            tbl_cand_data
        WHERE
            cand_qualification LIKE '%$emp_q%'
```

But it is not showing the expected result. I think my condition `cand_qualification LIKE '$emp_q'` is wrong.

My tbl_cand_data :[image]

Comment: `LIKE '%$emp_q%'` did you try this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing a [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) query you should include wildcards, as they will match a string containing, otherwise just do an exact match using =:

```
// String match
WHERE
    cand_qualification LIKE '%emp_q%';

// Exact match
WHERE
    cand_qualification = '$emp_q';

// You could try a WHERE IN clause as well
WHERE cand_qualification IN ('$emp_q');

// Values have to be quoted individually
WHERE cand_qualification IN ('BA','BSc','BCom');

// If you have an array you can do this:    
$myArray = array('BA', 'BSc', 'BCom');
$emp_q = "'" . implode("','", $myArray) . "'"; //Output 'BA', 'BSc', 'BCom'
```

Comment: I have changed to cand_qualification LIKE '%$emp_q%' but `var_dump` still shows empty array .`echo sql` is `SELECT cand_f_name, cand_l_name, cand_qualification, cand_phone, cand_email, cand_experience_yr, cand_experience_mn, cand_message, cand_id FROM tbl_cand_data WHERE cand_qualification LIKE '%BA,BSc,BCom%' `

Comment: Honestly, it's hard to tell what you are after unless we see schema and a few rows. It looks to me like you are storing data within the cand_qualifiation row with multiple CSVs (comma separated values). Are you looking for an exact match on 'BA,BSc,BCom'?

Comment: No. I want the list of candidates who have qualification BA or BSc or BCom

Comment: @SurajHazarika: Updated my solution, see if `WHERE IN` will work.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($emp_q)` and post the value.

Comment: `var_dump ($emp_q)` `string 'BA,BSc,BCom' (length=11)`

Comment: Got it. How are you building $emp_q, is it an array, and you are imploding it? You need to wrap each value within it's own set of quotes. I updated my solution with an example.

Comment: @Suraj do you understand that this won't work with your `PHP,Javascript,ASP ` field contents?

Answer (score 2):

> I saved it in database like this PHP,Javascript,ASP

## That's what you did utterly wrong.

you have to create a related table (that's why our ratabase called *relational* one!) storing qualifications, and interconnection table, consists of qualifications id linked with candidates ids.
And query them using basic joins.

Note that despite of your current decision, even if you decide to continue with your lame schema, you WILL have to remake it proper way, sooner or later (but sooner will make you less work).
That is the very basics of database architecture and noone can go against it.

```
SELECT fields FROM tbl_cand_data d, qualification q, qual_cand qc 
WHERE q.name = 'ASP' AND q.id=qc.qid AND d.id=qc.did
```

Comment: Thanks Col. Shrapnel...I will modify now

Comment: Pretty harsh attack on someone new to SO, I have no problem with others pointing out issues in code or design approaches, but cut the guy some slack. He may not have access to a DBA worth a damn.

Comment: Yeah, but than ALL other answers propagating LIKE are nice and comforting.

Answer (score -1):

Like requires percent %
try it